# Spring boot cache evict after cache built

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

We are using @Cacheable and @CacheEvict for cache implementation.

The problem is, to built the cache it takes more than 3 minutes. As per the application logic first the cache is getting cleared and then getting created. In between if any users access our application, application is not able to send the data as the cache is still being built.

Is there any spring way that first build the cache and then replace the old cache with the new cache(Apart from @CachePut).

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Comment: Maybe you should add some code here, as i know even if the cache is not built, the method with @cacheable could run correctly. I'm wondering why your application is not able to send the data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought add some coding, but didnt get. My scenraio is first build the cache and then replace with the existing cache. Will this be possible with @Cacheable ?

Comment: I still don't get what you expect the cache to do and I am not sure what you're trying to do. Can we take a step back and describe your use cases a bit more? You're saying that the cache takes "more than 3 minutes" to be built. What happens if one tries to access data during that time. Are you supposed to block ? Computing the data you're already computing in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call method  anotated with  @Cacheable inside @Cachevict. Since after clearing cache your @Cacheabe method gets called and load the data in that time gap?.But this is not a good practice for In Memory Cache since cache should be based on request.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "***", key = "#CACHE_KEY")
public void doStuff(){

}

@Schedule(cron = "${your time}")
@Cachevict
 public void clearCache(){
    log("Cache evicting");
    doStuff();
}
```